# Is it possible to set a mapping using ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, mapping, unittesting

I'm doing Unit testing and I need to set/add a mapping to my smart contract for some bypassing for a certain test case.

I have a mapping in my **smartcontract** like so:

`mapping(string => uint256) public claimTransactions;`

[image]

I have no problem reading the smart contract's mapping:

`await contract.claimTransactions("2");`
*returns a BigInt of the integer mapping of the passed string*
[image]

However, when I need to set a value or a mapping in my unit test file using ethers.js:
[image]

**I'm trying to mimic this line of code from my smartcontract** (solidity)
`claimTransactions[txId] = amount;`

[image]

*I need help if this is possible, or any reference that I can check on would be very helpful*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you defined the `claimTransactions` mapping, solidity automatically created a `getter` method for it, which you accessed by doing `claimTransactions(string)`. However, solidity does not automatically create a `setter` method for it, which is required to change the state.

You would have to define your own setter method and then call it in your javascript

```
function modifyTransactions(string memory txId, uint256 amount) public {
    //probably want onlyOwner or define some other logic to determine who can change the state
    claimTransactions[txId] = amount;
}
```

then in your javascript:

```
await contract.modifyTransactions("2", 1);
```

Comment: So a custom Setter method is needed huh. Alright then, thank you brother @kev1n!